# Horizontal scroll navigation like facebook or instagram - css

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, megamenu

I am having problem with my scroll navigation. or actully i am looking for a solution to mak a **horizontal scroll navigation** on mobile screen like most of the apps these days.
My menu is a mega menu is a mega menu and its working fine on both desktop and mobile.
when i use this code to make it horizontly scrollable its not opening the **mega menu**.

```
    ul{ /* set's the horizontal layout for the menu */
       white-space: nowrap;
       overflow-x: auto; 
       overflow-y: hidden;
       flex-wrap: inherit !important;
       scrollbar-width: none; /* this will remove scroll-bar for mozilla based browser */
}
    selector ul::-webkit-scrollbar { 
        /* now, let's remove the scroll-bar from the menu */
          display: none; 
        }
```

[Scrollable menu working but not mega menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ku0pJ.png)

if i remove overflow-x or y propertie then mega menu displays its content but the layout is like this.
[after removing overflow proprtie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GlGPp.png)

[My Mega Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cbXa.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're working on small devices you have to specify the media query like:

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {  
  .column {    
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;  
  }
}
```

Have you tried to set `max-width` and `max-height`?

You should Google about dropdown menus. This [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_mega_menu.asp) page explains how to pass it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please note that w3schools is a resource that most of the community will strongly advise against: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280478/why-not-w3schools-com